# How to invite users to join a multi player Gaming Session using Parse (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to develop a trivia app, much like Quiz Up but with multi players.

Here's what I thought of doing:-

Creating a class called 'Game Session' on Parse, that has information of who created it (`PFUser.current`), the name of the gaming session(name), and the names of users invited(invited_users). Think of this Gaming Session as a closed group where the users interact with each other only.

So there's a `createSessionViewController`, and a `joinSessionViewController`. 
If User A creates a gaming session (in `createSessionViewController`) and sends invites out to User B and User C, they get to accept or decline these invites in `joinSessionViewController`.

Now from what I have researched is that I would have to query through all the objects in the class Game Session (in `viewdidload` of the `joinSessionViewController`) and use `query.wherekey` for eg, User B's object id is in the column "`invited_users`". If so, I return that Gaming Session's object. Is that right?

If that is the case, is that an efficient way of doing it? Because it seems like if the app gets popular and there are lots of objects in the class, then it could take up a lot of time to get the one object with User B's id.
I hope I made myself clear and you guys understand my question.

PS: I'm sort of new to parse and swift, so if you could give me detailed answers it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct but I would also strongly suggest you take a look at Parse-LiveQuery. This tool allows you to subscribe to a `PFQuery` you are interested in. Once subscribed, the server will notify clients whenever a `PFObject` that matches the `PFQuery` is created or updated, in real-time.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX

Comment: From what I understand from the links you have provided is that PFLiveQuery would be useful when I actually enter the "Game Session" and there are edits made to it (via new questions, points tallies, turns etc). 

However, I would like to know if this would be a useful way to get the initial object of a Game Session with the user's object ID in viewDidLoad of joinSessionViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct and that is indeed one way you could go about doing that although it has drawbacks as you mentioned. If you felt like putting more effort into it, you can write JavaScript parse cloud code that executes after an item is saved (for example after a game session is created) and send out silent push notifications with the new objects id to the users who were invited. You could then use that push notification data to know the exact ids instead of having to query for them. This is much more advanced though. For whatever your app is, the simple route of having a model query the data on load should be fine. If you find yourself in a situation where performance is hindered due to this, well then congratulations.